# Editing/Updating user not working when using has_secure_password in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec-updating_users) to make my own user auth system. Everything is working fine when creating a new user. When trying to update a user is when things are no longer making sense. I am using the `has_secure_password` method. So I let it worry about taking the password and encrypting it. But when I update, some weird behavior occurs.

The important part is that I can update a user without entering any password and its confirmation. But if I enter a password and no confirmation, it requires a confirmation. If I only enter a confirmation password, that updates with no error. Now since `has_secure_paassword` is suppose to be doing that part, why is it not doing it when updating? One thing I did not add in my User model is a presence validation due to this line in the tutorial:

> Presence validations for the password and its confirmation are
>   automatically added by has_secure_password.

I am aware that there are similar questions on this, but none seem to enforce strong parameters, which is my guess as to why it is not working for me. Some of my code below.

**User Controller**

```
def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    # if params[:user][:password].blank?
    #   render 'edit'
    #   return
    # end

    if @user.update(user_params)
        redirect_to @user, notice: 'User successfully updated'
    else
        render 'edit', notice: 'Failed to update profile.'
    end
end
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
        :username, :email, :phone, :bio, :password, :password_confirmation
        )
end
```

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save {self.email = email.downcase}
  has_secure_password
  before_create :create_remember_token

  validates :username, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255, minimum: 5},
  format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]*\z/, message: "may only contain letters and numbers." },
  uniqueness: true

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
  #... Other User stuff.
```

**Edit form**

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
  <%= form_for(@user, :html => {:class => 'well'}) do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :username %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :username, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :phone %><br />
      <%= f.phone_field :phone, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :bio %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :bio, class: 'form-control' %> 
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Update", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the User form view to your question? It's probably `app/views/user/_form.html.erb` @Andy

Comment: @franksort I added that. But I tried something different as I included the quote. It seems `has_secure_password` isn't doing what the tutorial says its doing. At least in terms of updating. Works fine when creating a new user. But when updating it does't seem to recognize the password presence validation.

Comment: Thanks for your time @franksort but doesn't work if I add `:password_digest` to the strong parameters :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is an `update` action instead of a `create` the validations might not be running.

From [ActiveModel::SecurePassword](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password):

> Validations for presence of password **on create**, confirmation of password (using a password_confirmation attribute) are automatically added.

Relevant section of code from **secure_password.rb**

```
def has_secure_password(options = {})
  ...
  if options.fetch(:validations, true)
    validates_confirmation_of :password, if: lambda { |m| m.password.present? }
    validates_presence_of     :password, :on => :create
    validates_presence_of     :password_confirmation, if: lambda { |m| m.password.present? }
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Oh wow. So I see. Yes, that indeed answers the question as to why it happens. Thanks a lot for your help. Is there a way to override this so it also happens in the `update` action as well? I am still fairly new to rails :)

Comment: @Andy Glad I could help!  Something like `validates :password, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |user| user.password.present? }, confirmation: true, on: :update` in your `User` model might work.